# Why is Or not working in angularJs ng-pattern?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I am using the `ng-pattern="/^(([A-Za-z]{0,5}) | ([0-9]{0,10}))$/"` but the input control rejecting the input `"asd"` or `"09"` although I am expecting both should be accepted. Is this pipe symbol `|` not working as "OR"?

Comment: Remove the spaces around `|` - https://regex101.com/r/gK0mH4/1. The spaces inside JS patterns are always meaningful.

Comment: Did you try to remove the spaces around the pipe?

Comment: @Niitaku  Yes. Even Without space it is giving same result.

Comment: @Prashant My demo above says it is working. So, the problem is not the  `^([A-Za-z]{0,5}|[0-9]{0,10})$` regex. Post a fiddle. Update the question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes it is working. I needed to remove the "/" from begging and end of regex from scope variable. Thanks

Comment: Aha, so it is clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a scope variable, so, if you have `ng-pattern="regex"` in the `input`,  use

```
$scope.regex = /^([A-Za-z]{0,5}|[0-9]{0,10})$/;
```

The spaces around `|` are considered meaningful and are search for by the regex engine.